# Can't send request from applet to servlet

Tags: java, servlets, applet

I have the following code:

```
URL urlServlet = new URL(WEB_SERVER_URL);
URLConnection connection = urlServlet.openConnection();

connection.setDoInput(true);
connection.setDoOutput(true);
connection.setUseCaches(false);
connection.setDefaultUseCaches(true);
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");

connection.setRequestProperty("event", "blah");

OutputStream outputStream = servletConnection.getOutputStream();
outputStream.flush();
outputStream.close();
```

The server is not responding to this program.

But if I get inputStream from connection, I catch breakpoint in the DoGet servlet method.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: [this link](http://www2.sys-con.com/itsg/virtualcd/java/archives/0309/darby/index.html) may help you

Comment: At a guess, you probably want to set the method to something other than `GET`. `PUT` by the looks of it. And similarly for the servlet, don't use `doGet`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *But if I get inputStream from connection, I catch breakpoint in the DoGet servlet method.*
>
> *What am I doing wrong?*

Your mistake was to not asking for the response. The `URLConnection` is lazily executed. The request will only be sent whenever you ask for the response. Calling `getInputStream()` will actually fire the HTTP request because you're asking for the response. The connection will not be made when you just open and close the request body.

#### See also:

- [Using java.net.URLConnection to fire and handle HTTP requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793150/how-to-use-java-net-urlconnection-to-fire-and-handle-http-requests)